# python - html- inserting sibling element containing nested tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

**How to insert a sibling element containing nested tags ?**

I am trying to use the `insert_before` function but this seems to work only for single tag.
For example, having

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class= first_class>
    <h1 id=Heder1>Header1</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I try to insert above each `<div class= first_class>`

```
 <button class="accordion">
  <div class="preface">
    <i>Text</i>
  </div>
  </button>
```

I try to use below logic, but it doesn't work as expected. The section is not being inserted.

```
section_code = BeautifulSoup('<button class="accordion"><div class="preface"><i>Text</i></div></button>', 'lxml')

section = section.html.body.contents[0]

titels = soup.find_all("h1")

for title in titels:
    title.parent.insert_before(section)
```

How can this be achieved?

**Desired output**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button class="accordion">
      <div class="preface">
        <i>Text</i>
      </div>
    </button>
    <div class= first_class>
    <h1 id=Heder1>Header1</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please fix typo where your for loop iterates through `titelss` and not `titels`

Comment: i think you need to try to use `section_code` instead of `section` in the line of the loop. i mean in the line  `title.parent.insert_before(section)`

Comment: please refer the [documentation](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=insert_before)

Comment: corrected the typo in titles, this typo was not a problem though, the loop is working in my script

Comment: @stormfield using section_code instead of section doesn't work, it inserts the snippet in the wright place but adds unwanted tags for <html> and <body>, as it handles it as a complete html code

Comment: could you try to replace the parameter `'lxml'` with `"html.parser"` from the line first line in your code ? the line where you call beautiful soup with the said tags.

Comment: parser documentation of [beautiful soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#differences-between-parsers)

Comment: @Chris did it solve the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do a bit more. If you insert as `str` instead of `bs4.element.Tag`. The string will be html encode

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html>
  <body>
    <div class= first_class>
    <h1 id=Heder1>Header1</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

"""

insert = """

<button class="accordion"><div class="preface"><i>Text</i></div></button>
"""
insert_content = BeautifulSoup(insert,"lxml")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

title = soup.find("div")

title.insert_before(insert_content.find("button"))
print(soup.prettify())
```

Output

```
<html>
 <body>
  <button class="accordion">
   <div class="preface">
    <i>
     Text
    </i>
   </div>
  </button>
  <div class="first_class">
   <h1 id="Heder1">
    Header1
   </h1>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ kcorlidy the logic works on the self contained example, however when I pass the html code to the html variable html=BeautifulSoup(open('C://Folder/Test.html'),'lxml') then I get an error: 'Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lmxl. Do you need to install a parser library?' I use python 3.5. how need I pass the html code to the html variable to make the script working?

Comment: `fd = open('C://Folder/Test.html') html = fd.read() fd.close() soup = BeautifulSoup(html;,"lxml")` you can input a fd into BeautifulSoup

Comment: @ kcorlidy still the same problem. I tried to use the html.parser instead of lxml also, then I get a different error 'Cannot insert None into a tag'

Comment: @Chris i change `lxml` to `html.parser`, it still works. My env is py35, bs4-4.5.1. and print your content before you insert it, or use `if html:` to make sure it is not `None`

Comment: @ kcorlidy, worked. there was a problem with passing the argument to a loop. Thanks